# Creating resources combination

Tags: python, python-itertools

We have some departures which can be assigned to different arrivals, just like this:

```
Dep1.arrivals = [A1, A2]
Dep2.arrivals = [A2, A3, A4]
Dep3.arrivals = [A3, A5]
```

The output of this function should be a list containing every possible combination of arrivals:

Output: `[[A1, A2, A3], [A1, A2, A5], [A1, A3, A5], [A1, A4, A5], ...]`

Notice that `[A1, A3, A3]` isn't contained in the list because you can not use an arrival twice. Also notice that `[A1, A2, A3]` is the same element as `[A3, A1, A2]` or `[A3, A2, A1]`.

#### EDIT:

Many solutions given works in this case but not as a general solution, for instance if the 3 sets or arrivals are equal:

```
Dep1.arrivals = [A1, A2, A3]
Dep2.arrivals = [A1, A2, A3]
Dep3.arrivals = [A1, A2, A3]
```

Then it returns:

```
('A1', 'A2', 'A3')
('A1', 'A3', 'A2')
('A2', 'A1', 'A3')
('A2', 'A3', 'A1')
('A3', 'A1', 'A2')
('A3', 'A2', 'A1')
```

Which is wrong since `('A1', 'A2', 'A3')` and `('A3', 'A2', 'A1')` are the same solution.

Thank you anyway!

Comment: Well, since you can't find a pythonic solution, how about a non-python one? What did you try in that direction?

Comment: Did you actually *look* in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lol = [["A1", "A2"], ["A2", "A3", "A4"], ["A3", "A5"]]
>>> print [x for x in itertools.product(*lol) if len(set(x)) == len(lol)]
```

#### Result

```
[('A1', 'A2', 'A3'),
 ('A1', 'A2', 'A5'),
 ('A1', 'A3', 'A5'),
 ('A1', 'A4', 'A3'),
 ('A1', 'A4', 'A5'),
 ('A2', 'A3', 'A5'),
 ('A2', 'A4', 'A3'),
 ('A2', 'A4', 'A5')]
```

Note that this is notionally equivalent to the code that @Kevin has given.

***Edit***: As OP mentions in his edits, this solution doesn't work with when order of combination is different.

To resolve that, the last statement can be altered to the following, where we first obtain a list of sorted tuple of arrivals, and then convert convert the list to a set, as below:

```
>>> lol = [["A1", "A2", "A3"], ["A1", "A2", "A3"], ["A1", "A2", "A3"]]
>>> set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in itertools.product(*lol) if len(set(x)) == len(lol)])
{('A1', 'A2', 'A3')}

>>> lol = [["A1", "A2"], ["A2", "A3", "A4"], ["A3", "A5"]]
>>> set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in itertools.product(*lol) if len(set(x)) == len(lol)])
{('A1', 'A2', 'A3'),
 ('A1', 'A2', 'A5'),
 ('A1', 'A3', 'A4'),
 ('A1', 'A3', 'A5'),
 ('A1', 'A4', 'A5'),
 ('A2', 'A3', 'A4'),
 ('A2', 'A3', 'A5'),
 ('A2', 'A4', 'A5')}
```

Comment: I've edited my question because it gives a wrong solution in some scenarios. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @DWeiss23 Nice catch, have updated my answer, check edits. Don't forget to accept if the answer helps :)

Comment: Wow! Nice one! First time question I asked through stackoverflow.com and worked great! Thanks! I've accepted your answer btw. Why is it useful though?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `product` to generate all possible combinations of the departures, and then filter out combinations containing duplicates after the fact:

```
import itertools

arrivals = [
    ["A1", "A2"],
    ["A2", "A3", "A4"],
    ["A3", "A5"]
]

for items in itertools.product(*arrivals):
    if len(set(items)) < len(arrivals): continue
    print items
```

Result:

```
('A1', 'A2', 'A3')
('A1', 'A2', 'A5')
('A1', 'A3', 'A5')
('A1', 'A4', 'A3')
('A1', 'A4', 'A5')
('A2', 'A3', 'A5')
('A2', 'A4', 'A3')
('A2', 'A4', 'A5')
```

Comment: Almost what I was looking for, but it gives a wrong solution in some scenarios. I've edited my question to show it. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score -1):

The question is tagged with `itertools` but i suspect you did not look at `itertools.combinations`

```
arrivals = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']
[a for a in itertools.combinations(arrivals, 3)]
#[('A1', 'A2', 'A3'),
#('A1', 'A2', 'A4'),
# ('A1', 'A3', 'A4'),
#('A2', 'A3', 'A4')]
```

Comment: I don't think your second result, `('A1', 'A2', 'A4')`, is a valid combination, because A4 isn't in the third arrivals list.

Comment: -1. OP is not asking for sets of 3 arrivals from a single list, he is asking for combinations from 3 sets of arrivals, where all entities within the combination are different.